# What is the reason for IBOutlets being private in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

The generated designer.cs properties are private by default (at least without manual tweaking of generated code). This makes coding against something like a UITableViewCell feel much different than if I were doing this in Objective-C.

The popular way in the case of UIxxxViewCells, at least from what I can tell, is for the UIxxxViewDataSource to populate the IBOutlet properties, and that the cell should only be responsible for anything related to drawing/rendering the view.

With Xamarin.iOS, we are unable to access these properties from the data source, and instead are required to provide additional setter methods to populate the cell. In this way, the cell is responsible for setting it's own properties.

Is this just "The .NET way" of doing things?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's so that we don't break encapsulation by default.

The outlets belong to the object they're on, it should be able to choose whether they're able to be modified from the outside. The fact that they're properties is an implementation detail of the Xamarin.iOS outlets system - you should think of them as private fields.

If you wish to expose them, you can create properties that do so - preferably read-only.

Comment: So in your opinion is the fact that IBOutlets are usually bound to properties in a header a flaw in Objective-C? Or is the desire "not to break encapsulation by default" suggest my "The .NET way" comment is the real reason?

Comment: Pretty much everything is public in Objective-C. So yes, it's about "the .NET way" in so far as good encapsulation is the .NET way. It's the same reason we have properties instead of public fields.

Answer (score 3):

It was probably done that way because that's how the other GUI designers in MonoDevelop worked at the time (still do). Auto-generated bindings to the native controls used by the user-designed control for toolkits like Gtk# are also created as private.

I'm not sure if other UI designers for .NET work (I've never used Visual Studio to develop GUI apps using Windows.Forms or WPF).

Feel free to file a feature request on https://bugzilla.xamarin.com to make them public - I'll gladly implement it, I think it probably makes more sense for them to be public. I haven't changed it mostly because no one has expressed that they wanted it be any other way.

Comment: I asked around and ended up getting this as the response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147688/what-is-the-reason-for-iboutlets-being-private-in-xamarin-ios/18154631#18154631

Comment: I've just committed a patch which attempts to preserve any public/protected/internal accessibility specifiers that you put on the outlets yourself by editing the *.designer.cs files - this way at least it's somewhat of a compromise. The first time they are synced back from Xcode, they'll still be private, but if you edit them to be public, the sync logic should now preserve that when regenerating the file when syncing new changes made in Xcode.

Comment: FWIW, now that it's been explained to me by mhutch, I do see his point and it does make sense why they are private by default - basically, you should think of these outlets as fields instead of properties, it's just that they are "magic" fields that pluck their values from native land on demand.