# Designer.cs properties not keeping as Public

Tags: xamarin.ios

Recently Not sure why but properties in Designer.cs file is automatically changing to private instead public I have manually set.

```
[Outlet]
    [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
    public UIKit.UIButton btnEditRow { get; set; }
```

After some time.

```
[Outlet]
    [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
    UIKit.UIButton btnEditRow { get; set; }
```

Comment: Why do you expect the property to be public in the first place? This is generated code and will thus be generated every time something is changed in your storyboard. This is done to ensure encapsulation as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18154631/2399772).

Comment: I want to set button touchUpInside event in the viewController not in the cell. without making property public. How is that possible? P.S. This button is child of UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's Auto generated code, changing that to public is not solution. Xamarin will update it again to original. that's process. If you want to access it from other class, create get property of that control in .cs file.

for example

```
public UIButton btn_EditRow
        {
            get{
                return btnEditRow;
            }

    }
```

You can access btn_EditRow from other class.

Comment: This is good idea. Thanks. Only thing its still redundant. but until Xamarin provides some way for this. This work around is good.